# Android (Kotlin) Canvas undo operation problem

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas

Working on a draw project. The code is working, but the one thing, that i can't fix - undo operation.
It's work only for SmoothLine, not for Line, Rectangle etc.

```
class MyCanvasView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?): View(context, attrs) {

    companion object {
        const val SMOOTHLINE = 1
        const val LINE = 2
        const val RECTANGLE = 3
        const val SQUARE = 4
        const val CIRCLE = 5
        const val TRIANGLE = 6
    }

    var mCurrentShape = 1
    private val paint = Paint()

    private var scaleFactor = 1.0f


    private var motionTouchEventX = 0f
    private var motionTouchEventY = 0f
    private var currentX = 0f
    private var currentY = 0f
    private val touchTolerance = ViewConfiguration.get(context).scaledTouchSlop

    private val path = Path()

    private val stackPaths = Stack<Path>()
    private val stackPaint = Stack<Paint>()


    private lateinit var extraCanvas: Canvas
    private lateinit var extraBitmap: Bitmap
    private val backgroundColor = ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, R.color.white, null)


    public override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        extraBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width*3+300, height*3+500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        extraCanvas = Canvas(extraBitmap)
        extraCanvas.drawColor(backgroundColor)

    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas.drawBitmap(extraBitmap, 0f, 0f, null)
        when (mCurrentShape) {
            LINE -> onDrawLine(canvas)
            RECTANGLE -> onDrawRectangle(canvas)
            SQUARE -> onDrawSquare(canvas)
            CIRCLE -> onDrawCircle(canvas)
            TRIANGLE -> onDrawTriangle(canvas)
        }
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        motionTouchEventX = event.x * (1 / scaleFactor)
        motionTouchEventY = event.y * (1 / scaleFactor)

        when (mCurrentShape) {
                    LINE -> onTouchEventLine(event)
                    SMOOTHLINE -> onTouchEventSmoothLine(event)
                    RECTANGLE -> onTouchEventRectangle(event)
                    SQUARE -> onTouchEventSquare(event)
                    CIRCLE -> onTouchEventCircle(event)
                    TRIANGLE -> onTouchEventTriangle(event)
                }
        return true
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Line
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    private fun onDrawLine(canvas: Canvas){
        val dx = abs(motionTouchEventX - currentX)
        val dy = abs(motionTouchEventY - currentY)
        if (dx >= touchTolerance|| dy >= touchTolerance) {
            canvas.drawLine(currentX, currentY, motionTouchEventX, motionTouchEventY, paint)
        }
    }
    private fun onTouchEventLine(event: MotionEvent){
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                currentX = motionTouchEventX
                currentY = motionTouchEventY
                path.reset()
                path.moveTo(motionTouchEventX, motionTouchEventY)
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> invalidate()
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                extraCanvas.drawLine(currentX, currentY, motionTouchEventX, motionTouchEventY, paint)
                path.quadTo(currentX, currentY, motionTouchEventX, motionTouchEventY)
                addToStack(path)
                path.reset()
            }
        }
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    // SmoothLine
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    private fun onTouchEventSmoothLine(event: MotionEvent) {
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                currentX = motionTouchEventX
                currentY = motionTouchEventY
                path.reset()
                path.moveTo(motionTouchEventX, motionTouchEventY)
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                val dx = abs(motionTouchEventY - currentX)
                val dy = abs(motionTouchEventY - currentX)
                if (dx >= touchTolerance || dy >= touchTolerance) {
                    path.quadTo(currentX, currentY, (motionTouchEventX + currentX) / 2, (motionTouchEventY + currentY) / 2)
                    currentX = motionTouchEventX
                    currentY = motionTouchEventY
                }
                extraCanvas.drawPath(path, paint)
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                addToStack(path)
                path.reset()
            }
        }
        invalidate()
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Square
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    private fun onDrawSquare(canvas: Canvas){
        onDrawRectangle(canvas)
    }
    private fun onTouchEventSquare(event: MotionEvent){
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                currentX = motionTouchEventX
                currentY = motionTouchEventY
                invalidate()
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                adjustSquare(motionTouchEventX, motionTouchEventY)
                invalidate()
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                adjustSquare(motionTouchEventX, motionTouchEventY)
                drawRectangle(extraCanvas, paint)
                invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
    private fun adjustSquare(x: Float, y: Float) {
        val deltaX = abs(currentX- x)
        val deltaY = abs(currentY- y)
        val max = deltaX.coerceAtLeast(deltaY)
        motionTouchEventX = if (currentX - x < 0) currentX + max else currentX - max
        motionTouchEventY = if (currentY - y < 0) currentY + max else currentY - max
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Rectangle
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    private fun onDrawRectangle(canvas: Canvas){
        drawRectangle(canvas, paint)
    }
    private fun onTouchEventRectangle(event: MotionEvent){
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                currentX = motionTouchEventX
                currentY = motionTouchEventY
                invalidate()
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> invalidate()
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                drawRectangle(extraCanvas,paint)
                invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
    private fun drawRectangle(canvas: Canvas, paint: Paint) {
        val right = if (currentX > motionTouchEventX) currentX else motionTouchEventX
        val left = if (currentX > motionTouchEventX) motionTouchEventX else currentX
        val bottom = if (currentY > motionTouchEventY) currentY else motionTouchEventY
        val top = if (currentY > motionTouchEventY) motionTouchEventY else currentY
        canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint)
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Circle
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    private fun onDrawCircle(canvas: Canvas){
        canvas.drawCircle(currentX, currentY, calculateRadius(currentX, currentY, motionTouchEventX, motionTouchEventY), paint)
    }
    private fun onTouchEventCircle(event: MotionEvent){
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                currentX = motionTouchEventX
                currentY = motionTouchEventY
                invalidate()
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> invalidate()
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                extraCanvas.drawCircle(
                    currentX, currentY, calculateRadius(currentX, currentY, motionTouchEventX, motionTouchEventY),
                    paint
                )
                invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
    private fun calculateRadius(x1: Float, y1: Float, x2: Float, y2: Float): Float {
        return sqrt(
            (x1 - x2).toDouble().pow(2.0) +
                    (y1 - y2).toDouble().pow(2.0)
        ).toFloat()
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Triangle
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    private var countTouch = 0
    private var basexTriangle = 0f
    private var baseyTriangle = 0f
    private fun onDrawTriangle(canvas: Canvas){
        if (countTouch < 3 ) {
            canvas.drawLine(currentX, currentY, motionTouchEventX, motionTouchEventY, paint)
        }else if (countTouch == 3) {
            extraCanvas.drawLine(motionTouchEventX, motionTouchEventY, currentX, currentY, paint)
            extraCanvas.drawLine(motionTouchEventX, motionTouchEventY, basexTriangle, baseyTriangle, paint)
        }
    }
    private fun onTouchEventTriangle(event: MotionEvent) {
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                countTouch++
                if (countTouch == 1) {
                    currentX = motionTouchEventX
                    currentY = motionTouchEventY
                }
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> if(countTouch != 3) invalidate()
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                countTouch++
                if (countTouch < 3) {
                    basexTriangle = motionTouchEventX
                    baseyTriangle = motionTouchEventY
                    extraCanvas.drawLine(currentX, currentY, motionTouchEventX, motionTouchEventY, paint)
                } else if (countTouch >= 3) {
                    extraCanvas.drawLine(motionTouchEventX, motionTouchEventY, currentX, currentY, paint)
                    extraCanvas.drawLine(motionTouchEventX, motionTouchEventY, basexTriangle, baseyTriangle, paint)
                    countTouch = 0
                }
                invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------

    private fun addToStack(path: Path){
        stackPaths.push(Path(path))
        stackPaint.push(Paint(paint))
    }
    private fun restoreStacks(){
        extraBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        stackPaths.forEachIndexed { index, path ->
            extraCanvas.drawPath(path, stackPaint[index])
        }
        invalidate()
    }
    fun undoLastAction() {
        if (stackPaths.isNotEmpty()) {
            stackPaths.pop()
            stackPaint.pop()
        }
        restoreStacks()
    }

    fun changeProperty(brush: Brush){
        paint.color = brush.brushDrawColor
        paint.isAntiAlias = brush.brushIsAntiAlias
        paint.isDither = brush.brushIsDither
        paint.style = brush.brushStyle
        paint.strokeJoin = brush.brushStrokeJoin // default: MITER
        paint.strokeCap = brush.brushStrokeCap // default: BUTT
        paint.strokeWidth = brush.brushStrokeWidth
        paint.xfermode = brush.brushXfermodeode
        paint.pathEffect = brush.brushPathEffect
    }
    fun changeProperty(eraser: Eraser){
        paint.color = eraser.eraserDrawColor
        paint.strokeCap= eraser.eraserStrokeCap
        paint.strokeWidth = eraser.eraserStrokeWidth
        paint.xfermode = eraser.eraserXfermodeode
        paint.style = eraser.eraserStyle

    }
    fun changeProperty(hiliter: Hiliter){
        paint.strokeWidth = hiliter.hiliterStrokeWidth
        paint.color = hiliter.hiliterDrawColor
        paint.alpha = hiliter.hiliterAlpha

    }
    fun changeProperty(shapes: Shapes){
        paint.strokeWidth = shapes.shapesStrokeWidth
        paint.color = shapes.shapeshDrawColor
        paint.style = shapes.shapeshStyle
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
        extraBitmap.recycle()
        super.onDetachedFromWindow()
    }
}
```

How it looks now:
I draw a "LINE", when call undoLastAction method and the "LINE" stay on my extraCanvas, until I draw a new "LINE", same thing for the other shapes, except the case, when i use the "SMOOTHLINE", for this case it`s works perfectly.

How it should looks:
I want to ensure that the undoLastAction method works for all objects in the same way as for "SMOOTHLINE"

Comment: Just from quickly browsing your code, it appears the way undo works is you pop something off your path and paint stacks and then redraw the stack to the canvas. Well, you are not pushing any of your shapes to the stacks except for the smooth line, so it makes sense they don't reappear after an undo.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes, you are right that I am not adding any figures, except for the random line and the straight line, because the problem arose already at the stage of adding a straight line, so I did not see the point of continuing to add figures to the stack until now I don't solve the problem with a straight line